# Problems with Eclipse on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, 64-bit, out-of-memory

I'm using since today Eclipse on Windows 7 64bit. So eclipse is still pretty virgin, i just installed android plugin for it.

And I have many memory problems with it, which I didn't have with a worse computer however on 32-bit-Windows XP.

Did anybody make the same experience and what have you done to fix this out of memory errors?!

I read somewhere, that it's recommended to install beside JRE 64bit also the 32bit-version. Could it be true?

Thanks in advance,

Mur

Comment: What exact Java version are you using to launch and run your Eclipse? with 6u21 pre built7, you can have this kind of trouble: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, here is the answer:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514

Answer (score 1):

Try to set higher Heap size using following options in your eclipse.ini file:

```
  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

Here I am setting max heap size as 1024 MB.
eclipse.ini file can be found in eclipse installation directory.

check other VM options here :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a genuine problem due to an unknown incompatibility between OpenCV libraries and Windows 7 64-bit. I am not going to duplicate a huge amount of explanation why and what I am having trouble with so please follow my question raised in here http://answers.opencv.org/question/3996/cannot-do-anything-with-opencv-anymore-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 8 64-bit and you want to run Eclipse, follow these steps:

1. Unistall Java if you already have it.
2. Open Internet Explorer and go to the java official website.
3. [Java Official Downloads Page](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
4. Click on the 64-bit version of Java to download, and install it.
5. Download Eclipse 64-bit version from eclipse website.
6. [Eclipse Official Downloads Page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
7. Click on the 64-bit version to download the zip file.
8. Extract all (you can rename it to simply "Eclipse" for convenience).

Run eclipse.exe inside the "Eclipse" folder and it should run.
Pick your Eclipse workspace and get some coding working. Hope this helps!